Movie about couple lost in New York City at night
The plot goes like this: a couple drives to New York to do assorted things (shopping etc.) and leaves their car at a parking lot which is only open until the evening. When they return to retrieve the car, the parking lot has already closed; desperately, the husband attempts to climb over a fence to reach for the vehicle, but the guard dogs there impede him from doing so. And so the couple must spend the night roaming the city, venturing through not-so-friendly-looking places such as the underground and the sewers, roamed by (equally) not-so-friendly-looking people. In the ending, dawn comes and they return to the parking lot, retrieve the car, and everything is fine again.
I believe the movie from the 90s, and the setting too.

It's Final Jeopardy (1985). 
It's a made-for-TV thriller starring Richard Thomas and Mary Crosby that was directed by Michael Pressman.
IMDb




Wikipedia:

Marty (Thomas) and Susan (Crosby) Campbell are a small town couple
  visiting a large, somewhat unfriendly, declining city. They
  accidentally get lost and stranded in a deserted, rundown neighborhood
  after dark when Marty gets the wrong address for meeting a business
  client and are both left behind by a cab that drops Susan off after
  dark from shopping and whose taxi business requires callers to have
  business names and phone numbers before sending any cabs after dark.
  The parking lot that their rental car is in is locked until 6:00 AM,
  leaving them unable to retrieve it before then. After Marty barely
  escapes getting hit by a newspaper delivery truck, they both find a
  nearly deserted apartment building but no phone to use. Marty and
  Susan go back to the locked parking lot to try to get their rental car
  to drive back to their hotel. When Marty climbs the fence, two
  Dobermans attack him and he drops the car keys and barely escapes with
  his life.Marty calls the police from an outdated payphone that still
  requires coins to obtain a dial tone for emergency calls to try to get
  help but is told that since he trespassed on the locked parking lot,
  he can't file a complaint. Susan wanders away and is spotted by a gang
  in a neighboring alley and runs back to Marty, who the police hung up
  on. They're chased through another alley and barely escape again.
  Marty finds another payphone that also needs coins for emergency calls
  and tries to get help again, but the gang leader catches him, forcing
  the usually non-violent Marty to fight back and Marty and Susan barely
  escape again. They hide in an abandoned theatre but flee when they
  find a corpse. Then they find a man and try to offer him money to
  drive them to their hotel, but the man is scared off.
  Next, they find
  an unstable derelict (Jeff Corey) who sends Marty on a wild sewer
  chase to a non existent police station. Marty and Susan leave the
  derelict and wander down another rundown, empty street, where Marty
  breaks store windows in frustration over the lack of police response,
  setting off its alarms. They're sent to a subway by an untrustworthy
  street kid only to find it locked, but also find a burglarized church
  that was vandalized by the gang and sneak into through its broken-open
  door. They find an incapacitated junkie whose also-druggie sister
  thinks they're inside a hospital and that Marty is a doctor.Another
  gang member appears, giving the sisters directions to another subway
  to get home on which Marty and Susan overhear while hiding, meaning
  that both of these girls are members of this gang. Marty's watch has
  stopped and they find the subway's revolving gate locked to them but
  manage to squeeze in just as the gang finds them again and chases them
  through the subway. Marty drives the E-train while the gang enters the
  train and pulls the cord to stop it. Marty and Susan abandon the
  train, Susan is sent to hide while Marty lures the gang into another
  tunnel, where he knocks a pile of rubble onto three of its members and
  lures its leader into the boiler room, blinding him with steam and
  beating him to death with a large wooden board.
  He goes back above
  ground and finds Susan telling a policeman (Dennis Farina) about their
  ordeal, who ironically, says "Glad to be of service" to a disgusted
  Marty. They go to their hotel to get cleaned up and change their
  clothes, return to the parking lot to retrieve their rental car and
  drive away after paying a $5.00 overnight fee to its attendant that
  found its keys but has no change if they didn't have the exact amount.
  The attendant tells them to be more careful next time and Marty and
  Susan drive off towards home.

VHS trailer / 
TV promo
